# Using wildcard subdomain with rewrite rule and page id as parameter user.domain.com/pageid

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, wildcard

I am wondering how I can produce the following domain .Website.com/

I have got the .website.com working with

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.website\.com
RewriteRule .* viewuser.php?username=%1 [L]`

But when I try to add additional parameters onto the end of the rewrite (so I can use a _GET) it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for the QSA (QueryString Append) parameter. It appends the old query string to the new URL (?id=... → ?username=...&id=...)

You can simply add it to your parameters by replacing `[L]` with `[L,QSA]`.

More information about how that works can be found in the Apache Documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to NOT add query string parameters to the URL in the rewrite rule, but to let PHP parse the URL and deal with such a special or general case. Usually this does implement some important business rules or technical rules that power features, and the rewrite rules are not the best place to put them - although you are able to use regular expressions, making fancy rules with them tend to get unreadable. And it is a second place to look for code and behavior.

However, if you want to add query string parts inside the `RewriteRule` in addition to the ones already present in the query, you have to add the `QSA` flag, so the last line would be

```
RewriteRule .* viewuser.php?username=%1 [L,QSA]
```